# Create my own process name and show in Top Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, process, build

I Learning about process Linux and I know how to create a simple hello world in c.

but I want to create a program (process)  with the name I choose and  show in Top (Time Process Monitor)
Example:
Show my program name in column COMMAND
[image]

I want to monitor individual threads of the program once they are created, I would like to see the details (e.g., CPU/memory usage) of individual threads.

¿What is the procedure to accomplish this?
Thanks for reading

Comment: What have you tried this far? It's expected that you show some effort of your own in terms of actual code. Please, consider taking a look at [some guidelines about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: try with continuous execution. you can see the process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All processes running on Linux system will be displayed by the top command. It is the name of the executable in the COMMAND column. If you want specific name, rename your program to that specific name and run it. The top command displays limited number of processes by default. If your program is not consuming lot of resource then it will not there in the default list. You can use -n parameter to increase the number of processes displayed to list all processes.

In your hello world program just add a sleep statement(e.g. sleep(60)) and run it. Then check in the "top -n 1000" output.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know how work this.